# xslt loop through attributes using namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I've been trying to loop attributes of a XML that have namespace, after sometime I was able to get elements using namespace, but now I'm getting a hard time to loop through attributes.

All examples I've found works without namespace on it.

This is what I have so far:

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:x="TransactionDataOfRequest">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="//x:form">
      <xsl:value-of select="//x:name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:copy-of select="//x:request"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- newline character -->
    <xsl:value-of select="//x:qform"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<transaction xmlns="TransactionDataOfRequest" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <success>true</success>
  <code>0</code>
  <value>
    <request>INC000158</request>
</descript>
    <qform>Save</qform>
    <form>
      <add name="ADM_1" title="B" type="String" isList="false">Americana</add>
      <add name="ADM_2" title="Question?" type="String" isList="false">No</add>
      <add name="ADM_3" title="State" type="String" isList="false">ss</add>
    </form>
  </value>
</transaction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default namespace declaration like `xmlns="TransactionDataOfRequest"` only applies to element nodes, not to attribute nodes. So you would select an attribute simply as e.g. `//x:form/x:add/@title`.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I was getting a hard time to find where I was wrong.